# Erro Uncaught SyntaxError ao atribuir valores em Objeto no Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
var modelo = 'Yamaha Fazer 250';
var fabricante = 'Yamaha';
var moto = {'Modelo - '+ modelo: fabricante};
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte código de erro:

> VM200:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +

Comment: acho que não pode concatenar o nome do atributo ali, poderia fazer com o valor: `{'Modelo':  modelo + fabricante}`

Comment: mas pode usar os conchetes assim: `['Modelo - '+ modelo] : fabricante`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na seguinte linha:

```
var moto = {'Modelo - '+ modelo: fabricante};
```

coloque chaves paraq resolver esse incidente:

```
var modelo = 'Yamaha Fazer 250';
var fabricante = 'Yamaha';
var moto = {['Modelo - '+ modelo]: fabricante};
```

Fonte:
[Propriedades computadas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_colon_after_property_id)

Answer (score 2):

Olá, farofino!

O aviso

`VM200:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +`

Diz que há uma token inesperado, no caso, é o sinal de adição. Você não pode concatenar o nome do seu atributo, apenas o valor dele (o da direita). Para resolver, faça o seguinte

```
var modelo     = 'Fazer 250';
var fabricante = 'Yamaha';
var moto       = { modelo: fabricante + modelo };
```